# How can I write my SQLite queries more efficiently in my Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I'm coding a small app for Android using Jetpack Compose.  I have a SQL database in my app with a field called "findDay" which contains the days of the week, MONDAY through SUNDAY.

In my DAO I'm calling a separate SQL query for each day of the week. I'm sure this is inefficient.

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT() FROM finds WHERE findDay=\"MONDAY\"")
     suspend fun getMondayTotal():Float

    @Query("SELECT COUNT() FROM finds WHERE findDay=\"TUESDAY\"")
    suspend fun getTuesdayTotal():Float

    @Query("SELECT COUNT() FROM finds WHERE findDay=\"WEDNESDAY\"")
    suspend fun getWednesdayTotal():Float

    @Query("SELECT COUNT() FROM finds WHERE findDay=\"THURSDAY\"")
    suspend fun getThursdayTotal():Float

    @Query("SELECT COUNT() FROM finds WHERE findDay=\"FRIDAY\"")
    suspend fun getFridayTotal():Float

    @Query("SELECT COUNT() FROM finds WHERE findDay=\"SATURDAY\"")
    suspend fun getSaturdayTotal():Float

    @Query("SELECT COUNT() FROM finds WHERE findDay=\"SUNDAY\"")
    suspend fun getSundayTotal():Float
```

Here's my repository.

```
suspend fun getMondayTotal():Float {
       return findDao.getMondayTotal()

   }

    suspend fun getTuesdayTotal():Float {
        return findDao.getTuesdayTotal()

    }

    suspend fun getWednesdayTotal():Float {
        return findDao.getWednesdayTotal()

    }

    suspend fun getThursdayTotal():Float {
        return findDao.getThursdayTotal()

    }

    suspend fun getFridayTotal():Float {
        return findDao.getFridayTotal()

    }

    suspend fun getSaturdayTotal():Float {
        return findDao.getSaturdayTotal()

    }

    suspend fun getSundayTotal():Float {
        return findDao.getSundayTotal()

    }
```

Here's my Viewmodel.

```
suspend fun getMondayTotal(): Float {
        return repository.getMondayTotal()
    }

    suspend fun getTuesdayTotal(): Float {
        return repository.getTuesdayTotal()
    }

    suspend fun getWednesdayTotal(): Float {
        return repository.getWednesdayTotal()
    }

    suspend fun getThursdayTotal(): Float {
        return repository.getThursdayTotal()
    }

    suspend fun getFridayTotal(): Float {
        return repository.getFridayTotal()
    }

    suspend fun getSaturdayTotal(): Float {
        return repository.getSaturdayTotal()
    }

    suspend fun getSundayTotal(): Float {
        return repository.getSundayTotal()
    }
```

Here's my UI.

```
@Composable
fun FindsGraph(viewModel: MainViewModel) {

    var mondayval: Float by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var tuesdayval: Float by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var wednesdayval: Float by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var thursdayval: Float by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var fridayval: Float by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var saturdayval: Float by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var sundayval: Float by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val scope2 = rememberCoroutineScope()


    scope2.launch {
        mondayval = viewModel.getMondayTotal()
        tuesdayval = viewModel.getTuesdayTotal()
        wednesdayval = viewModel.getWednesdayTotal()
        thursdayval = viewModel.getThursdayTotal()
        fridayval = viewModel.getFridayTotal()
        saturdayval = viewModel.getSaturdayTotal()
        sundayval = viewModel.getSundayTotal()
    }


    val bardata = listOf(
        BarData(mondayval, "MONDAY", color = Color(0xFF00BCD4)),
        BarData(tuesdayval, "TUESDAY", color = Color(0xFFFFEB3B)),
        BarData(wednesdayval, "WEDNESDAY", color = Color(0xFFF44336)),
        BarData(thursdayval, "THURSDAY", color = Color(0xFF4CAF50)),
        BarData(fridayval, "FRIDAY", color = Color(0xFF673AB7)),
        BarData(saturdayval, "SATURDAY", color = Color(0xFFDF780B)),
        BarData(sundayval, "SUNDAY", color = Color(0xffed615d))
    )




            Column (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()){


                BarChart(
                    dataCollection = ChartDataCollection(bardata),
                    barSpacing = 10.dp,
                    axisConfig = AxisConfig(
                        showAxes = true,
                        axisColor = Color.Black,
                        axisStroke = 10f,
                        minLabelCount = 3,
                        showGridLabel = true,
                        showGridLines = false

                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(400.dp)
                )
            }


        }
```

So, this method works.  It displays a nice graph for me in the end but I also realize this is a real brute force way to go about this, I'm sure there is a much more efficient way to do this.  I really appreciate any help refining this.

Comment: If you already have working code, and just want feedback, consider posting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we all been there and no one will get mad about your code as long as you want to learn that all that matters.

second, yeah there is a much better way actually to make what you did and that is by passing a paramater to you function in `Dao` that holds the needed day:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT() FROM finds WHERE findDay= :dayOfWeek")
 suspend fun getDayOccurrences(dayOfWeek : String):Float
```

now you will have to pass this parameter all the way from you UI down to this `Dao`.

Repository:

```
suspend fun getDayOccurrences(dayOfWeek : String):Float {
    return findDao.getDayOccurrences(dayOfWeek)
}
```

and you continue like this so that all you need to do is pass the right day from the UI.

**Note: I highly advice you to have a `variable` for each day or a `List` for all days in your `viewModel` then you collect the occurrences inside your `viewmodel` using `ViewModelScope` because the current way you're doing it will cause `scope2` to be triggered everytime a `Recomposition` accurs.**

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `GROUP BY` clause. Statement like this:

```
SELECT findDay, COUNT() FROM finds GROUP BY findDay;
```

will return rows with the name of the day and number of it's occurrences. To use this with room, you will have to use [`@RawQuery`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery). The whole code can look like this:

```
data class DayWithCount(
    val findDay: String,
    val count: Int,
)

@Dao
interface MyDao {
    @RawQuery
    suspend fun getDaysWithCount(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): List<DayWithCount>
}

class Repository {
    suspend fun getDaysWithCount(): List<DayWithCount> {
        val query = SimpleSQLiteQuery(
            "SELECT findDay, COUNT() AS count FROM finds GROUP BY findDay"
        )
        return dao.getDaysWithCount(query)
    }
}
```